# How to make JQuery Draggable in Meteor work with touch devices?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, meteor

I am learning Meteor and JQuery and created a project in Meteor that uses JQuery UI Draggable.  This works fine in Desktop Browsers. I assumed that it would work in Mobile devices when dragged with fingers but it isn't (thats why we have JQuery Mobile).  Is there anyway I can create a application that works in both Desktop browsers and be able to use it mobile.  This might be a silly basic question but I don't know how to progress. Would appreciate some directions

Answer (score 0):

[Could that be](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch) of some use to you?

Basically, it should translate touch events such as tap in mouse events such as click.